# Facebook setUserData alternative for logEvents

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-facebook, cordova-plugin-facebook-connect

I would like to know if there is any method I can provide facebook with user's `email, phone, fn` via `logEvent` with the plugin [cordova-plugin-facebook-connect](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect)

Facebook documentation states that `setUserData` has to be used, but that method is not exposed on the Plugin. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/advanced-matching/

Is it possible to achieve the same results by passing those properties in the `logEvent` call?

Answer (score 0):

As of v3.1.0 of `cordova-plugin-facebook-connect`, you can now use `facebookConnectPlugin.setUserData`.